# Android: Modify a list in Firebase database

Tags: android, database, list, firebase

I am making an android app using firebase database. I have a table that contains both lists and other types.
I need to add more items to the list "colors".

I am trying to do it like this, but it doesn't work. Can someone help me with this.

```
        DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tableA");
    dbRef.child("colors").push().setValue("black");
```

Firebase database:

```
 "tableA" : {
"colors" : [ "red", "blue" ],
"size" : 20,
"weight" : 6.2}
```

Comment: hi can you please post an image of the output in your database with this code? thanks

Comment: @Gastón Saillén      java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()

Comment: At what line do you get that error?